# MVC complex business logic responsibility

Tags: java, model-view-controller, object

I have a little question about MVC:
For example if I have a model "Video" and the application allow the user to add/remove favourite videos (handling the favourites in a database for example). 
What is the correct approach for implementing that?

1. The class Video has **isFavourite()** / **addToFavourites()** methods. When called the Model access to the database adapter and updates the proper value.
2. Both Video an VideosManager have isFavourite() / addToFavourites() calls. When some method calls **video.addToFavourites()**, the Video model calls to **VideoManager.addToFavourites(this)**
3. Only the VideoManager implements **isFavourite(Video)** / **addToFavourites(Video)** methods. When someone wants to change the favourites calls directly to the VideoManager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Video can be a favorite for a specific User. Giving the class Video isFavorite()/addToFavorite() methods get's this relation wrong. So options 1 and 2 are not viable.

This seems to favor option 3. But I would like to place a side note. What is a VideoManager? The User should be responsible for managing her favorite videos, doesn't she?

So in my opinion there should be a model for Video's and Users. A View for Videos would have the option for a user to signal that it is a favorite. This action calls a controller that adds/removes the video from the User's set of favorites.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't the favourites modelled in a first class way as well?

I would introduce a class to represent the favourites and use that as the place that performed the persistence (probably by delegating to the `VideoManager` class that you've described).

```
class Favourites {
   public void addFavourite(Video video);
   public bool removeFavourite(Video video);
}
```